# Export Access form into same excel sheet as exported subform

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access

I have a form with a subform in a datasheet view which and I would like them both to be exported into same excel file.

I am exporting the subform using this code I found, which works great but I would like to add to it the main form data as well.

```
Private Sub Command457_Click()
    
    On Error GoTo Command13_Click_Err
    Me.ProstojeSubform.SetFocus
    
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
    Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With xlapp
    .Workbooks.Add
    .ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
    False
    .Cells.Select
    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Visible = True
    .Range("a1").Select
    
    End With
    
    Command13_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub
    Command13_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command13_Click_Exit
    
 End Sub
```

I can export the form itself using OutputTo or the built in export but not sure how to combine them into one excel file.

Comment: Is the main form filtered to a single record? If not, entire recordset will export. Have you considered exporting a report instead?

Comment: The form itself actually is just displaying bunch of calculated fields it is not bound to any record source. The default export function puts each of the field as a column, which is what I am looking for only with the subform data as well.

Comment: Where do you want the main form data to go, above the subform data? Can populate cells of worksheet by direct reference `.Range("A1").Value = Me.textboxname`. Then need to paste the subform data to a lower row. Select cell before pasting.

Comment: Above the subform data is preferable .

Comment: So did you try suggestion?

Comment: Yes, it works. As always thanks for the help, June.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can populate cells of worksheet by direct reference `.Range("A1").Value = Me.textboxname`.

Then need to paste the subform data to a lower row. Select cell before pasting.